# Not able to login to Oracle db from other user

Tags: oracle, database-administration, tns

I am not able to connect with other user except using `sys as sysdba`. I am giving an error `ORA-12154`

While tnsping is working and trace route is also working.

```
sqlplus devtest@p7ru01.ab.com
Sqlplus 19.0.0.0.0
Enter password 

Error 
ORA -1254 :TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

But I am able to login to db using sysdba, but not other db user.

Comment: please provide the output of `tnsping p7ru01.ab.com:<<port>>/<<sid>>`

Comment: Tnsping from local giving output in 30 sec

Comment: show the output of tnsping in the question itself, with port and sid or service name.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you incorrectly transcribed the output instead of copying and pasting.  The error code associated with ':TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified' is ORA-12154, not 'ORA -1254'.

That said, the net is full of references to ORA-12154, including my own article on it, [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/).

In short, it could not resolve 'p7ru01.ab.com' to an actual connect string - host name or IP address, port number, and database service name. Either it couldn't find an entry for 'p7ru01.ab.com' in the tnsnames.ora file, or it could not locate a tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens , but we are able to loging through sysdba  with same tns file, but other user other then sysdba not able to login

Comment: @bp_db - so you say, but you have not actually shown it.  Please update your question to show a copy and paste of the complete successful connection - most importantly including the actual full sqlplus command.